# SharePoint Search is not working on the hidden libraries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-search

I have configured SharePoint search and everything is working fine, but for some reasons I have to hide some libraries. After hiding those libraries, search results are not coming up for the items under those libraries. Is it expected or is there any way where I can configure to show the results from the hidden libraries.

Answer (score 0):

how did you hide libraries?
If you have changed permissions (in order to restrict users to access those libraries) there is no way for search to return results from that libraries.
Search returns only those items that are accessible (in terms of access rights) for user performing the search.

Comment: Using simple pnp PowerShell command for Hiding the library Set-PnPList -Identity $ListName -Hidden $False

Comment: Hello, ok now I understant. With this approach based on my knowledge the list is not indexed anymore, so items are not searchable. Moreover, I am just thinking about reasons to hide the list and wanted to be searchable - if you search items in hidden list, you have access to the items -> whole list. So the purpose of hiding it is? However I found some answers that if you create list, add items that are crawled and searchable and after that you hide list, it should be searchable (answers were for older on prem Sharepoint versions) - have you tried it?.